# How to get the date of last Sunday of current month with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-processing

I have to fire a query on last Sunday of each month at 23:59:59. Please someone help me to figure out the query to write and how to run the same automatically every last sunday

Comment: You might find [the MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySQL event scheduler which does the hob for you.

To create an event ,

```
CREATE EVENT myenvent 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY  EVERY interval STARTS timestamp [+INTERVAL] ENDS timestamp [+INTERVAL].
DO **query_to_fire**;
```

The schedule interval should e provided how often the query needs to be run and the statements under "DO" represents the query that has be executed.

If event scheduler is not enabled, you need to enable it by

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
adddate(last_day(curdate()),-mod(weekday(adddate(last_day(curdate()),1)),7))
```